# Using loops in dataframe with row

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, input

I am managing a dataframe with bike data (parking number, street, latitude and longitude, anchors, etc). My goal is to create a function that, on the one hand, through an input, asks the user on the screen for the parking number where it is located, then I want to verify that this number is in the idunplug_station column of the dataframe that I am handling. Once verified the next level would be to save in two variables, the longitude and latitude of the parking number.

The problem this has is in the loop that does not enter correctly I understand that it may be due to an indentation or something like that, likewise when I generate an else I also have problems since it prints it.

```
result_destino = ""
origen = int(input("Indica el nº de la estación donde te encuentras: "))
destino = int(input("Indica el nº de la estación a donde vas: "))
for i, row in stations_2019.iterrows(): #tomo como referencia el dataframe de estaciones 2019 para obtener latitud y longitud
    if i == origen:
      result_origen = row[10], row[11]
    else:
      print("No existe esa estación")

for j, row in stations_2019.iterrows():   
      if j == destino:
        result_destino = row[10], row[11]
      else:
      print("No existe esa estación")

print(result_origen)
print(result_destino)
```

Comment: "The problem this has is in the loop that does not enter correctly" are you getting any error?

Comment: As currently shown, the second `else` block is going to give an `IndentationError` anyway (the second `print` nees to be indented more)

Answer (score 0):

Your loops need to look like this:

```
for i, row in stations_2019.iterrows(): 
    if i == origen:
        result_origen = row[10], row[11]
        break
else:
    print("No existe esa estación")  # means: "that station doesn't exist"
```

The `else` goes with the `for`, and executes if the loop completes without encountering `break`. It is different meaning from with `if`, although the same keyword.

You would probably also want to do something else in the `else` block to prevent execution continuing, or you are going to hit a `NameError` later when you try to use `result_origen`.  You could raise an exception, or `return` if it is inside a function, for example.  Or if not, then at least ensure that `result_origen` is set to something (maybe `None` or `''`).